# Insert a value into a specific specific index with numpy

Tags: numpy

For example, when there is an array like the one below, is it possible to insert a new [1] only in 2,2 index and make it [0,1]?

before

```
array([[[0],
        [0],
        [0]],

       [[0],
        [0],
        [0]],

       [[0],
        [0],
        [0]]])
```

after

```
array([[[0],
        [0],
        [0]],

       [[0],
        [0],
        [0]],

       [[0],
        [0],
        [0, 1]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible with numpy because numpy requires that arrays are *rectangular*. In this case, you're working with a 3x3 array, and your 'after' example violates this (the last row would have 4 elements).

You could do this with a list of lists, but that would have performance implications if you are working with large arrays.